# Can refreshing the cooling system save this motor?

Tags: engine, coolant, dodge, overheating, avenger

I bought my 2011 Dodge Avenger less than a year ago and after 6 months started having issues with running cool.

I took it to the dealer and ended up needing a new head and head gasket. After the repair they told me that my coolant had been mixed and I needed an entire new system. They refused to give me a quote to do the repairs because my '2011 Avenger is not worth it' now that my car is running cool again I called the dealer and they said I need a whole new motor not just a new heating/cooling system.

Can I just replace the heater core, radiator, hoses, pump and do a flush with a good quality cleaner or do I really need a new motor?

And yes, ever since I found out about the issues I have been fighting with the dealer I bought the car from because they sold it to me with the coolants mixed and I took it there for all of my services.

Comment: Even with mixed coolant (coolant and oil mixed) I don't know why you would need a whole new system, seems a bit excessive. As for the new engine it seems as though there shouldn't be a problem. You can actually replace your coolant fairly easily yoursefl for less than $50. Maybe try that first? Otherwise take it to 2 or 3 other garages to ask for opinions.

Comment: I had a complete flush done and the problem keep coming back. It sounded excessive to me and that is why I am asking. I didn't know of anyone else that has had issues or repairs. My mechanic that I typically use is working with me, and says it seems excessive to, he has never had this issue before but knows that mixing antifreeze can cause serious issues if not caught and corrected quickly. Who knows how long this car had mixed Antifreeze in it. All I know is that it is not running right

Comment: It's good you have a trusted mechanic working on it. Is the car running rough as a result of "running cool"?

Comment: By “running cool” I assume you mean that the coolant temp gauge is not getting up to where you expect... is that correct? If that is what you mean, then my question is what running issues is it having? Is the engine running rough or lacking power? Or is it just that the gauge is not ever reading normally?

Comment: The gauge on the dash yes reads cool operating temp, the engine is under powered and running improperly. At the shop at times the engine is running below expected operating temperate and other times warm